# Factory de Relação N:N

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou com uma aplicação onde os usuários podem ver ou não determinado módulo do sistema de acordo com suas permissões. Essas permissões são gravadas no banco de dados de forma *N:N* e gerenciadas no `UserPolicy`, conforme exemplo:

**UserPolicy.php**

```
public function viewReports(User $user)
{
    foreach($user->module as $m){
        if($m->id === 3)
            return true;
    }
}
```

**UserPolicyTest.php**

```
public function testCanViewReports()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->make();
    $user->module()->sync([3]);

    $this->assertTrue($user->can('viewReports', User::class));
}
```

O teste passa, só que os dados registrados com **$user->module()->sync([3]);** ficam gravados no banco de dados (na tabela `user_module`).

> **Como faço para que os registros sejam excluídos, ou não precisem ser
>   criados, no banco de dados?**

Comment: Para min não ficou claro, *user_module* é a tableta de ligação enter o modulo  e o usuário. Sua pergunta é: saber como **NÂO** usar essa tabela e mesmo assim ter a ligação entre usuário e modulo? Ou entendi errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar um rollback de todas as alterações do seu teste, você pode usar uma trait dentro da classe teste.

importe a DatabaseTransactions e use dentro de seu teste da seguinte forma.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\User;

// Importe a DatabaseTransactions
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    // Use a trait DatabaseTransactions dessa forma
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function testSeuTesteAqui()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        // Aqui o usuário vai ser criado mas quando o teste terminar ele não existirá mais.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta é clara, porém, o processo de construção lógico um pouco equivocado. Vamos lá...

Laravel disponibiliza 2 funções para gerenciar relacionamentos N:N, `attach()` e `sync()`. A função attach() registra novos valores na tabela auxiliar, enquanto sync() excluí todos e então registra novos valores.

Chamar a função sync() e não desejar que a tabela seja alterada é ilógico.

Se a resposta acima foi util para você, tudo certo, se não, continue lendo.

Talvez a pergunta que você tenha que fazer é:

> **Por que estou me preocupando se os registros são inseridos/alterados?**

Então, assumo que você utiliza **o mesmo banco de dados** para desenvolvimento local e para testes, isso **dificulta o desenvolvimento TDD**, resultando em situações como a que você enfrenta.

Minha sugestão:

Crie um novo banco de dados ou, o que é recomendado: instale e utilize o `SQL Lite`.

Em `config/database.php`, configure uma nova nova conexão (se optou por utilizar o recomendado, a conexão com o sqllite já vem configurada).

Abra o arquivo `phpunit.xml` e adicione a seguinte linha na tag `php`.

```xml
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqllite" />
```

Onde, `value=""` recebe o nome da conexão.

Espero ter ajudado. :D

Comment: Obrigado, muito valorosa a dica de usar o SQLite para os testes. Mas ainda gostaria de uma forma de não gravar os dados no banco de dados, como é feito com o usuário.

Comment: Neste caso, MySQL Transactions pode ser o que você procura. Você inicia a transaction e faz rollback para não refletir as alterações no banco. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions